# Generating MD5 of a file inputstream in groovy

Tags: groovy, md5

I am trying to generate md5 of a file inputstream but I'm noticing that the generated md5 is different than the one generated from running command line `md5` against the file on disk. Is this correct way to generate md5?

```
DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, MessageDigest.getInstance('MD5')) 
println "MD5 generated from Groovy: " + dis.getMessageDigest().digest().encodeHex().toString()
```

Comment: You need to read the bytes from `dis` for it to calculate the md5 hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DigestInputStream` calculates the digest of the files you send through the stream. As you didn't consume the stream, you are calculating the MD5 sum of an empty file. Do `md5sum` on an empty file and you will get the same sum you are getting from your Groovy code. Add `dis.eachByte {}` between your two code lines and you will get the correct MD5 sum for your file.